# Exclude all hidden directories in UNIX find

Tags: unix, find

I'm doing a word search using the following command:

```
find . -exec grep -q [some_word]  '{}' \; -print -o -name .svn -prune -o -name .ssh -prune -o -name .boneyard -o -name log -prune -prune -o -name tmp -prune
```

Is it possible to use a regex to exclude all hidden directories?

Note:
The current command traverses the entire tree from the current location and exclude those being pruned.  The exclusion needs to work for any hidden directory regardless off location.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `regex` flag of `find`:

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -exec grep -q [some_word] {} \; -print -o -name .svn -prune -o -name .ssh -prune -o -name .boneyard -o -name log -prune -prune -o -name tmp -prune
```

Also, please read the [manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Comment: I tried this and various other methods and couldn't get the output to match.  I see now my problem is with 'grep -q'.  Thanks for the quick response.